# Image control from Database in VB6

Tags: database, vb6, image

I have some images stored in a database and I want to populate an image control. All the examples I can find copy the image to the hdd and then use loadpicture to put it in the image control. Is there a way to push the image directly in without going to the hdd first?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some sample code that should get you there fairly easily:

http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=29004&lngWId=1

This assumes you have the image in a byte array.  You can use standard DB functions to get your image out and into a byte array.

Answer (score 0):

If the database holds the image in typical serialized form (as it would exist in a file) then you can use WIA 2.0 to load the retrieved Byte array and produce a StdPicture object you can assign to the Image control's Picture property.

[Windows® Image Acquisition Automation Library v2.0 Tool: Image acquisition and manipulation component for VB and scripting](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=a332a77a-01b8-4de6-91c2-b7ea32537e29&displaylang=en)

This can handle PNG and TIFF as well as the usual suspects (GIF, JPEG, BMP).